# How to decipher a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all, regex-negation

```
preg_match_all('/({\$([^}]+)})/', $result, $matches)
```

Can someone please help decipher the regular expression in this call?

Regular expressions are not my best. As far as I can tell it's looking for matches that look like `{$foo}` but I think I am missing something?

Comment: Yes https://regex101.com/r/WS9jkL/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we have a rather simple expression that passes pretty much all chars, bounded from left with `{` and `$` and bounded from right with `}`. It collects almost all chars in between:

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/LwBi21/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LwBi21/1/). For example, we can restrict it and fail special chars, if we like:

```
({\$\w+})
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/o4LtrJ/1)

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /({\$\w+})/gm;
const str = `{\$foo}
{\$foo_090_}
{\$foo_@#\$%_5678}
{\$foo_@#\$%_{+[]:}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### PHP Test

```
$re = '/({\$\w+})/m';
$str = '{$foo}
{$foo_090_}
{$foo_@#$%_5678}
{$foo_@#$%_{+[]:}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```